# What's the difference between ModelAndView and ModelMap?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is `ModelMap` just the new name in Spring 3 for a `ModelAndView`?

Does the functionality change in Spring 3?

Consider this code in a Spring 3 app using a `ModelMap`:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/order", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public final String setup(final ModelMap model)
 {
  model.addAttribute(ORDER, new Order());
  return "setup";
 }
```

I would like to know what the equivalent use here of `ModelAndView` would be in an older Spring app? Would it just require a name change from `ModelMap` to `ModelAndView` to get this working in Spring 2.5?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ModelAndView`, as its name suggests, contains the model, *and* the name of the view. `ModelMap`, in contract, only contains information about the model.

Your example would have been written (in "old" Spring) as

```
 public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 {
  return new ModelAndView("setup", ORDER, new Order());
 }
```

Comment: About the new spring 3: If I return only ModelMap, then how is the view returned? Newbie here...

Comment: @Abhijeet: Spring will infer the view name from the request URI.

Comment: if i want to specify a view name explicitly ? So that I can use the same controller for different requests.

Comment: what about a Model m ?

Answer (score 10):

@coder247 Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't need to return a ModelMap. Add your attributes to your ModelMap and simply return a String which is the View name.

This is an excellent article that explains how to do this and more...
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/

Comment: + 1 for pointing out **"you don't need to return a ModelMap"**.